# innerHTML of each link not working

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
function DOMinnerHTML($element)
{
    $innerHTML="";
    $children=$element->childNodes;
    foreach($children as $child)
    {
        $tmp_dom=new DOMDocument();
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child,true));
        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML());
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}

$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtmlFile('http://www.google.com/');
$links=$doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $m)
{
    echo DOMinnerHTML($links[$m]).'<br />';
}
```

And it outputs nothing.

How can I do so that it outputs the content of each link in all `http://google.com` ?

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What page contents do you get? Does it contain any `a` elements?

Comment: @Pekka The rendered page is completely empty.

Comment: No, what page contents do you get from *Google*? Does `$links` contain anything? You know, debugging. On a quick glance, `$links[$m]` looks wrong. Shouldn't it be just `$m`?

Comment: Neither `$m` nor `$links[$m]` output something. But the "for" loops 27 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems this:

```
echo DOMinnerHTML($links[$m]).'<br />';
```

should be just this:

```
echo DOMinnerHTML($m).'<br />';
```

Comment: Thank you, bingjie2680 and Pekka! That was the error. (I thought that `foreach($links as $m)` was the same as `for(var m in links)` in JS).